# How to utilize all GPUs when dealing with pytorch code?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I have 2 GPUs and when I am working with pytorch code, only one GPU is used. I tried `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python xxx.py`, but occurs

> 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: command not found'

problems. I have also tried to add the following lines in object py file:

```
 import os    
    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"    
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"
```

but still only one GPU is utilized.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-former-torchies-parallelism-tutorial-py

Comment: That `command not found` error for setting environment variables looks like you're running something on Windows, but that's the syntax for setting environment variables on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parallelize the training data to each GPU seperatly. Data Parallelism is implemented using `torch.nn.DataParallel`. An example [from the pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class DataParallelModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.block1 = nn.Linear(10, 20)

        # wrap block2 in DataParallel
        self.block2 = nn.Linear(20, 20)
        self.block2 = nn.DataParallel(self.block2)

        self.block3 = nn.Linear(20, 20)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.block1(x)
        x = self.block2(x)
        x = self.block3(x)
        return x
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a somehow similary error. Im using `nn.DataParallel(self.net).to(self._device)` to parallelize and move it to the device. If I've got only one CUDA device everything works out. But if I use 2 devices, I'll get a `RuntimeErroor` due to a size misatch in my net (`RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 144], m2: [288 x 256] at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:249` ). I'm using a batch size of 16, so there shoudn't be any problems regarding separating the data to the devices. Do you have an idea what's going on?